# Should I merge these two supervisor scripts into one? If so, how?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

So I have three processes I'm aiming to daemonize on Elastic Beanstalk: daphne, a celery worker, and celery beat. I have these two files:

04_daemonize_daphne.config

```
files:
 "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_daphne.sh":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     # Get Django environment variables
     djangoenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
     djangoenv=${djangoenv%?}
     
     # Create daemon configuration script
     daphneconf="[program:daphne]
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b :: -p 5000 dashboard.asgi:application
     
     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/stdout_daphne.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/stderr_daphne.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10
     
     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600
     
     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true
     
     environment=$djangoenv
     "
     
     # Create the Supervisor conf script
     echo "$daphneconf" | sudo tee /opt/python/etc/daphne.conf
     # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
     if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         then
         echo "" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "[include]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "files: daphne.conf" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
     fi
     if ! grep -Fxq "[inet_http_server]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         then
         echo "" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "[inet_http_server]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "port = 127.0.0.1:9001" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
     fi
     
     # Reread the Supervisor config
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread
     
     # Update Supervisor in cache without restarting all services
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update
     
     # Start/restart processes through Supervisor
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart daphne
```

05_daemonize_celery.config

```
files:
 "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     # Get django environment variables
     celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g' | sed 's/%/%%/g'`
     celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

     # Create celery configuraiton script
     celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
     ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A dashboard --loglevel=DEBUG

     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10

     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600

     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true

     ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
     ; so it starts first
     priority=998

     environment=$celeryenv

     [program:celeryd-beat]
     ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A dashboard --loglevel=DEBUG --workdir=/tmp -S django --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid

     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10

     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600

     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true

     ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
     ; so it starts first
     priority=998

     environment=$celeryenv"

     # Create the celery supervisord conf script
     echo "$celeryconf" | sudo tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

     # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
     if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
       then
       echo "[include]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
       echo "files: celery.conf" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
     fi

     # Reread the supervisord config
     sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

     # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
     sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

     # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-beat
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```

If I remove 05_daemonize_celery.config from the deployment, daphne's daemon runs correct. But as soon as I include it, it stops working. I'm guessing because of the part where supervisord.conf is changed (where it looks for the [include] there). I am not sure as to how I should change this though, as I know pretty much nothing about bash. So should I merge these files for daemonization into one or just change the one for celery so that they work together?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up joining them. This is my final script:

```
files:
 "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_daphne_celery.sh":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     # Get Django environment variables
     djangoenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g' | sed 's/%/%%/g'`
     djangoenv=${djangoenv%?}
     
     # Create daemon configuration script
     daphneconf="[program:daphne]
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b :: -p 5000 dashboard.asgi:application
     
     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/stdout_daphne.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/stderr_daphne.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10
     
     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600
     
     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true
     
     environment=$djangoenv
     "

     # Create celery configuration script
     celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
     ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A dashboard --loglevel=DEBUG

     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10

     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600

     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true

     ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
     ; so it starts first
     priority=998

     environment=$djangoenv

     [program:celeryd-beat]
     ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
     command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A dashboard --loglevel=DEBUG -S django --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid

     directory=/opt/python/current/app
     user=nobody
     numprocs=1
     stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
     stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
     autostart=true
     autorestart=true
     startsecs=10

     ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
     ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
     stopwaitsecs = 600

     ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
     ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
     ; taking care of its children as well.
     killasgroup=true

     ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
     ; so it starts first
     priority=998

     environment=$djangoenv
     "
     
     # Create the Supervisor conf script
     echo "$daphneconf" | sudo tee /opt/python/etc/daphne.conf
     echo "$celeryconf" | sudo tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf
     # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
     if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         then
         echo "" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "[include]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "files: daphne.conf celery.conf" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
     fi
     if ! grep -Fxq "[inet_http_server]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         then
         echo "" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "[inet_http_server]" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
         echo "port = 127.0.0.1:9001" | sudo tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
     fi
     
     # Reread the Supervisor config
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread
     
     # Update Supervisor in cache without restarting all services
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update
     
     # Start/restart processes through Supervisor
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart daphne

     # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-beat
     supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```